# VoiceOver is not able to read mobile web

Tags: ios, mobile, accessibility

I have been away from accessibility\programming for awhile and I am helping friend with his responsive web site. We have fixed the code parts for accessibility on the desktop and Android\Talkback is usable. The issue is that VoiceOver, in iOS 12.14.5, doesn't recognized any content on the page. I remember running into an issue like this with earlier versions of iOS but can't remember the solution. I can't do any code because my peculiar that way. Any suggestions, sorry for the lack of code.

Comment: stick a link to the page if you can't provide the code here, without seeing what you have done there could be 200 different things that could cause this. This question will get closed otherwise as it 'needs details or clarity'. I haven't marked it for closing yet to give you chance to respond so we can help you :-)

Comment: To be clear it is not my code, it was something I notice on their website while evaluating it. It does work with Android\TalkBack with out any isues.

Comment: Sorry, forgot link, https://www.medtronic.com/us-en/index.html